# Edit an item and print the whole content with jq

Tags: json, bash, jq

Say I have a JSON like this:

```
{
    "user" :
    {
        "name": "Manu",
        "songs": 30
    },
    "admin" :
    {
        "name": "Chao",
        "songs": 50
    }
}
```

And I want to replace `user -> songs` to 40 and print the whole file, so that I get:

```
{
    "user" :
    {
        "name": "Manu",
        "songs": 40        <------ this is the line to change
    },
    "admin" :
    {
        "name": "Chao",
        "songs": 50
    }
}
```

How can I do this with [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/#) (using `jq version 1.3`)? I tried the following, which successfully replaces the value but, then, does not print the whole thing:

```
$ jq "[.user | { "name": .name, "songs": 40 }]" myfile
[
  {
    "songs": 40,
    "name": "Manu"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the assignment operator:

```
jq '.user.songs = 40' myfile
```

Comment: So with the assignment operator then the "print content" is done automatically?

Comment: I think so. I have to admit, I wasn't sure this would work until I tried it. My guess is that assignments are somehow "separate" from other "selection" filters, so lacking any other selections, the entire output is printed.

Comment: That's good news. Now I read in [jq manual -> Basic filters](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters):  _The absolute simplest (and least interesting) filter is .. This is a filter that takes its input and produces it unchanged as output._.

Comment: On closer reading of the [docs for the `=` operator](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.3/#\`=\`), I see that the input is the object (with keys "user" and "admin"), and the output is the same entire object, but with the given modification made.